# `:call append!` -- how vim insert line (append or setline) while respecting indentation

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, indentation, external-command

I want to put a string function output in my vim when press `xx`. My current working example is:

```
nnoremap <silent> xx :call append('.', 'string_output')<CR>
```

However, this put a line without respecting the indentation. In current setting it set the whole line from beginning and do not respect the indentation. Based on vim help I can use `append!` but that lead to error on extra parenthesis. The syntax according to vim help is `:{range}a[ppend][!]`, am I missing something?

*As an alternative I tried `setline` in which I expects to complete the line from current cursor (not beginning of the line) so it respects the current cursor position (aka indentation).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `!` in specific, you're mixing up the `append()` function (which you can use with `:call`) with the Ex command `:append`. While they have the same name, they're pretty different things (as in general, in Vimscript, with functions and Ex commands.)

Functions such as `append()` and `setline()` will typically not preserve indentation. For one thing, since they can append or modify an *arbitrary* line of the buffer, which indentation to copy might be a hard question to answer... Also, Vimscript functions typically try to depend less on the behavior of options such as `'autoindent'` and friends.

So, if you want to use the `append()` function and preserve indentation of the current line, you have to do that yourself. You can, for instance, use the `indent()` function, which will return the number of spaces that are equivalent to the indentation of the current line, together with the `repeat()` function to prepend those spaces into the appended string:

```
:call append(repeat(' ', indent('.')) . 'string_output')
```

There are quite a few limitations to this approach. For one, this will always indent using spaces and not tabs (regardless of the `'expandtab'` setting), it will also indent unconditionally regardless of the `'autoindent'` setting and will also only copy indentation of the current line and not respect `'indentexpr'` which might decide on a different indentation for the next line...

For those reasons, it's often more productive to use an Ex command or a normal mode command (such as `i` or, in this case, `o`) to append or modify lines, when you want to preserve indentation and other features of the text that Vim typically managed during normal text editing.

The interface for `:append` is a little awkward (entering multiple lines ending on a line with just a dot), but it's still possible to use it from a mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> xx :append<CR>string_output<CR>.<CR>
```

It might be easier to use the `o` Normal mode command though:

```
nnoremap xx ostring_output<Esc>
```

You also mentioned the `!` in `:append`, but note that `:append` will by default do whatever the current `'autoindent'` setting is set to do (either preserve or ignore indentation), so typically that's what you want... The `:append!` command will do the *opposite* of the current `'autoindent'` setting, but in a sense it still depends on it.

I also imagine that the `string_output` in your question is just an example. Using the result of a function or an expression is much easier in a function call such as `append()`, but still can be done in `:append` or `o` by using the `<C-R>` shortcut to recall the contents of a register, possibly combined with the expression register `=` which allows you to enter an expression.

For example:

```
nnoremap <silent> xx :append<CR><C-R>='string_output'<CR><CR>.<CR>
```

(Note you need two `<CR>`s in a row, one to finish entering the expression for the expression register, and another to finish entering the line in `:append`.)

Also:

```
nnoremap xx o<C-R>='string_output'<CR><Esc>
```

In these examples, I still used `'string_output'`, but hopefully it's clear that any other valid Vimscript expression would be also possible here.

Comment: First thanks for multiple solutions, clarification and the description. I ended up using your first solution using `indent()`. The reason I endup with using append() instead of normal/Ex mode in the first place was bcz instead of 'string_output' I use concatenation of two external bash script's output. Also, I wanted the whole process in silent which means I don't want vim to throw a subshell, ask for ENTER and then append. Currently I'm working on your next solutions but right now I couldn't use them with `system()` and `systemlist()` commands in place of 'string_output'.

Comment: @PiTao Nice that one of them worked for you already! I just tried `nnoremap xx o<C-R>=system('...')<CR><Esc>` with a command that produces a couple lines of output and that worked for me. You might want to use a `trim(system(...))` to drop the final newline from there. If your `system()` command outputs odd/non-standard characters, that might present an issue... Feel free to post a follow up question about that if you think you could use more help with that!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it works. I had problem with concatenating two commands which I'm doing it with `nnoremap xx o<C-R>=system("foo()")<Esc> <C-R>=system("bar()")<CR><Esc>`

Comment: @PiTao You can also use the string concatenation operator `.` as in `o<C-R>=system('foo').system('bar')<CR><Esc>`.

Comment: Nice. I really need to fundamentally take a course on vim. There are so many such tricks which I can't find easily. Thanks

Comment: @PiTao If you'd like to learn more on Vimscript, this is an excellent place to start: https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/